# How to create a list at center page with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm planning to create a list such that it is in middle of the page using Bootstrap 3 (latest). Any heads up ??

The list is expected to be at the center of the page

```
___________________________________________
|                                          |
|                                          |
|        ++++++++++++++++++++++            |
|        +                    +            | 
|        +                    +            |
|        ++++++++++++++++++++++            |
|                                          |
|__________________________________________|
```

Expected List is like 3 columns which should not stack on reducing the page width and should remain as below :

I'm planning to put an image in 1st column and 3rd column and put some text in middle one

```
 __________________________________________
 |        |                      |        |
 |        |                      |        |
 |        |                      |        |
 |________|______________________|________|
 __________________________________________
 |        |                      |        |
 |        |                      |        |
 |        |                      |        |
 |________|______________________|________|
```

Comment: If you can add more details I will help you out, but I can't understand what you are looking for. Do you have the columns matter sorted out?

Comment: No, I'm unable to figure out whether I should use divs or should I go for li's

Comment: Also Im unable to understand what should I do with the latest bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code for you to work with:

Create a "centre" class in CSS as follows:

```
div.centre{
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Then add it to your element as follows:

The secret to centralisation is in the **margin:0px auto;**, this is the convention of modern web development to centralise content.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood correctly, to reproduce the above structure you need the following code:

```
<style>
ul {
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
</style>

<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3>
Left side content here
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6>


<ul>
<li>list item</li>
<li>list item</li>
<li>list item</li>
</ul>


</div>

<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3>
Right side content here
</div>
```

The numbers (3) and (6) represent the width of the columns with 100% being (12). So (6)=50%, (3)=25%. Changing these will change the width. -xs -sm -md -lg mean the screen size. You should read the bootstrap docs for this. Everything else is obvious.